# Community uses old version of a changed and deployed lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I have a lightning component in my community (Partner Central template).

It works well, but I needed to make some changes, so I have done all my changes in my sandbox and deployed to my production via ant.

After a successful deploy of all components, the community still uses  the old version of my component - how can that be?

In Salesforce dev-console - the code shows the new version, in chrome dev-tools the html is of the old version.

How can that be?

Do I miss something?

BTW - it is an active community and I have publish changes although changes where made only for the component.

Thanks
Itai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

I have tried many things but all failed - even adding the component to an object's  record page - this showed the new version, but the community still showed the old version.

So eventually, I changed the code of the component on my production (just added a dumb line, via developer console, and saved it - only after that, my community refreshed the component and showed the new version.

I believe this is some kind of a bug, but anyway - now all is OK.

Itai

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to us. Page was returning a blank page. Went in and edited the javascript part of the page (js) , and resaved and then the page started working. Would be nice to know why this worked. No code was changed!